# Confused about object and dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

I don't get the difference between passing the instance of an object to passing a dereferenced object. I have

```
class A
{
public:
  A() {}

  void m() {}
};

void method(A& a)
{
  a.m();
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  method(A());
  return 0;
}
```

The call above does not work with compiler errors:

```
In function 'int main(int, char**)':
error:no matching function for call to 'method(A)'
note: candidates are:
note: void method(A&)
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'A&'
note: void method(B&)
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'B&'
```

But if I write

```
method(*(new A()));
```

it does.

Can anyone please tell my why and how to resolve the problem if I cannot change the method I want to call?

Comment: (Non-constant) references cannot bind to temporary values.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Since you posted this as a comment please also provide the dup ;)

Comment: @honk: "*The* dup"? :-)

Comment: @honk Is this question a duplicate(dup)?

Comment: I am wondering why Microsofts compiler can generate working code out of this or it just tries to fool people with don't saying a single word.

Comment: @user1760653, Microsofts compilers are notoriously non-standard compliant.

Comment: Still not a reason for letting people do stupid things.

Comment: @user1760653, Than don't use C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Why not? I can use GCC.

Comment: @user1760653, If I recall correctly, GCCs errors aren't much more descriptive. You still need to know and understand these common issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are creating a temporary object:

```
method(A()); // A() here is creating a temporary
             //     ie an un-named object
```

You can only get `const&` to temporary objects.
So you have two options:

1. Change the interface to take a const reference.
2. Pass a real object.

So:

```
// Option 1: Change the interface
void method(A const& a)  // You can have a const
                         // reference to a temporary or
                         // a normal object.


// Options 2: Pass a real object
A a;
method(a); // a is an object.
           // So you can have a reference to it.
           // so it should work normally.
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you create a temporary object that you try to pass to `method`.
A temporary object cannot be modified (it doesn't make sense to modify it, it will be gone the moment `method` returns). So to pass a temporary by reference, you must pass by a **const reference**.

```
void method(const A& a)
{

}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense but why does GCC don't tell me that in a way where _const_ occurs in the error?

Comment: @user1760653 Because it doesn't know what you're trying to do, it only knows what you're doing.

Comment: @user1760653, Becuase what GCC sees is only you trying to call a function with signature `void method(const A&)`. But it wasn't declared.

Answer (score 1):

If this were legal, horrible things would happen. Consider:

```
void addOne(double& j) { ++j; }

int q = 10;
addOne(q);
```

This would create a temporary `double`, add one to it, and leave your original `q` unmodified. Ouch.

If `method` modifies its parameter, your code is broken. If it doesn't, it should take a `const` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Problem that you see is that your function accepts only lvalue of type A. To solve the issue you can either change your function to accept type A by value:

```
void method( A a ) {}
```

or by const reference:

```
void method( const A &a ) {}
```

or by rvalue reference (if you use C++11):

```
void method( A &&a ) {}
```

or pass lvalue of type A to your method:

```
A a; method( a );
```

If you want to understand the problem deeper read about [lvalue](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/127955-what-lvalue) in c++